# Move only jpg files from folder and subfolder to another folder without duplicating

Tags: vbscript, move, filesystemobject

I use the below script to move all the specific files to destination folder. I want to copy the files to destination folder without duplicating.

As I am going to schedule to run the VBS for every 10 minutes, it should not again copy the same files which are already present in the folder.

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

testfolder = "D:\env"
'fso.CreateFolder(testfolder)

MoveFiles fso.GetFolder("D:\Movie Keys\License\2013_Apr_19")

Sub MoveFiles(fldr)
    For Each f In fldr.Files
        basename  = fso.GetBaseName(f)
        extension = fso.GetExtensionName(f)

        If LCase(extension) = "env" Then
            dest  = fso.BuildPath(testfolder, f.Name)
            count = 0
            Do While fso.FileExists(dest)
                count = count + 1
                dest  = fso.BuildPath(testfolder, basename & "_" & count & "." _
                        & extension)
            Loop
            f.Move dest
        End If
    Next

    For Each sf In fldr.SubFolders
        MoveFiles sf
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Will your destination folder keep the same folder structure, or do you want to copy all source folders/subfolders to a single destination folder?

Comment: And if all files should go into the same destination folder, should existing files be preserved or overwritten?

Comment: The destination folder going to remain same and i want to only copy the file types *.*env to the destination folder.But source folder will contain many many sub folders so the script should find all *.*env files and process. And if already the file exist in destination it should not copy the existing one it should copy only the unexistance files and existing file should remain same with out changes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that you want to copy all source files (including those in sub folders) into 1 destination folder. At this point there are chances that files will have the same file name and you may have files overwritten during the copy or files will be skipped as it will see it as a duplicate.

You're trying to achieve this with the following code

```
        count = 0
        Do While fso.FileExists(dest)
            count = count + 1
            dest  = fso.BuildPath(testfolder, basename & "_" & count & "." & extension)
        Loop
```

The problem is, you'll not know which file corresponds to which source file.

I suggest you rename the file as the full path. So, let's assume your source folder looks like:

[image]

In both the FolderExample and sub01 there is a file called image01.jpg.

I've used the underscore here to separate each folder (which may or may not be realistic for you). But by creating this new file name it means you cannot overwrite any other file with the same name!

[image]

Now, if you need to use the file again, the problem is the file name has changed. The good thing about using the underscore here is you can program another application to copy the file, split by underscore and then create the full path, get the file name and copy files accordingly.

This means, you can replace

```
    If LCase(extension) = "env" Then
        dest  = fso.BuildPath(testfolder, f.Name)
        count = 0
        Do While fso.FileExists(dest)
            count = count + 1
            dest  = fso.BuildPath(testfolder, basename & "_" & count & "." _
                    & extension)
        Loop
        f.Move dest
    End If
```

with

```
    If LCase(extension) = "env" Then
        dest  = fso.BuildPath(testfolder, f.Name)
        if not (fso.FileExists(dest)) then
            f.Move dest
        end if
    End If
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment actually rather than over writing i dont want to copy the existing files. When i run the scrypt it should not again copy the already copyed files it should copy only the files which is newly added in source folder

Comment: Then you just need to do *IF NOT fso.FileExists(dest) THEN dest = fso.BuidPath(testFolder, basename......) END IF*

Comment: The same way i want to add few lines in this script and it should work for two types of files. That is *.*key files should go for key folder and *.*Env files should go for env folder

Answer (score 1):

If you want to synchronize folders without creating duplicates and without copying files that already exist in the destination, simply use `robocopy`:

```
robocopy "D:\Movie Keys\License\2013_Apr_19" "D:\env" *.env
```

Or in a [batch](/questions/tagged/batch) script:

```
@echo off

set dst=D:\env
set src=D:\Movie Keys\License\2013_Apr_19

robocopy "%src%" "%dst%" *.env
```

---

**Edit:** Since you want to mangle the source tree into the destination folder, `robocopy` won't work in your case. Your existing code is close to what you want, but since you don't want to overwrite existing files and also don't want to create "versioned" copies you need to change this:

```
count = 0
Do While fso.FileExists(dest)
    count = count + 1
    dest  = fso.BuildPath(testfolder, basename & "_" & count & "." _
            & extension)
Loop
f.Move dest
```

into this:

```
If Not fso.FileExists(dest) Then f.Move dest
```

---

For using various destination folders depending on the extension you could use a dictonary to store the destination paths:

```
Set testfolder = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
testfolder.CompareMode = vbTextCompare  'case-insensitive
testfolder.Add "env", "D:\env"
testfolder.Add "key", "D:\key"
```

and change your code like this:

```
If testfolder.Exists(extension) Then
  dest  = fso.BuildPath(testfolder(extension), f.Name)
  If Not fso.FileExists(dest) Then f.Move dest
End If
```

Comment: That depends on which additional switches are used. By default `robocopy` will update a destination file if a source file with the same name has a newer modification date. This can be suppressed by using the `/xn` switch (exclude newer).

Comment: I don't think this will help then (despite me giving you a +1)! I've had to re-read the OP several times. He wants to copy the content of many source folders to a single destination folder! This means there is a great chance of files with the same name being sent to the destination folder with chances of files being overwritten or not copied (my new answer expands on this)

Comment: `robocopy` won't mangle a folder tree. Files from subfolders will go into the same subfolder under the destination folder. If the source tree should be mangled, `robocopy` would not be an appropriate soultion, but the OP would then need to define whether existing (destination) files should be replaced or preserved.

Comment: But my source folder will contain many sub folders so it has to search in all subfolders for the file type *.*env

Comment: No sub folder should not be preserved. it should copy the files from (source)D:\Movie Keys\License\2013_Apr_19 to (destination)D:\ENV

Comment: Your edit is pretty much identical to mine, even to the way it is laid out!!

Comment: @DaveRook It's the obvious thing to do. What about it?

Comment: The same way i want to add few lines in this script and it should work for two types of files. That is *.*key files should go for key folder and *.*Env files should go for env folder

Comment: @Ansgar Wiechers - Can you please write the full script

Comment: SO is not a "do my work for me free" site, and integrating the suggested changes is actually quite simple. You just need to replace `testfolder = ...` and `If LCase(extension) = "env" Then ... End If` with the new code. Consider this your homework.